# Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic aside from at singularities with isolated singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

All the examples I've been able to come up with are either non-holomorphic or fail the condition. For example, with the 1D case we can take $$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$$ With singularities at $\pm i$. If we try to extend this to some $$f(z,w) = \frac{1}{1+(z+w)^2}$$We now have singularities at $z=-w\pm i$ Which is not at all what we wanted.

Comment: An entire function cannot have singularities (read again!). the answer to your question is yes. But not only yes, read(!) the principle of isolated zeroes. Again, read!

Comment: Sorry, I made the question too vague. I've rephrased my question somewhat. I'm quite sure the principle of isolated zeros does not hold for several complex variables, is this incorrect?

Comment: The zeros/poles of meromorphic functions of two variables are union of curves : no isolated points. For functions of $n$ variables it will be submanifolds of codimension $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hartogs extension principle (simple version using Hartogs figure suffices) means that there are no isolated singularities.  There aren't even any compact singularities.  If a function has an actual nonremovable "singularity", then that singularity will go off to infinity somehow, just like in your example.